# Is there a way to trigger an activity on a chrome custom tabs resume?

Tags: android, android-customtabs

I don't think there's a way to do this but I wanted to double check.

I have some web content being loaded in a chrome custom tab, and the content could be sensitive in nature.

The android app has a PIN screen, which we would like to show when the custom tab resumes, but I don't see any way to do this, or believe it's possible.

Can this be done with custom tabs, or will the web app need to implement their own PIN screen?

Comment: well, assuming this custom tab is opened in your app you can always lock screen from calling `Activity`s side. but if you manage only web side I'm also affraid that you don't have option to force-lock device...

Comment: @snachmsm ya it's in my app.  I've found that there's a onNavigationEvent callback that I might be able to work with, I just can't get it to work yet.  The whole CustomTabServiceConnection isn't triggering onCustomTabsServiceConnected yet.  Hopefully once that's working the callback will function as i need.  Otherwise my app doesn't trigger any lifecycle events when the custom tab resumes

Comment: Issue was with targeting SDK 30.  I guess something to do with the chrome package and the new package manager changes it didn't like so the service wouldn't bind.  Tomorrow i can figure out if my entire workflow will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a callback when you bind a custom tab service that will alert you when a tab is shown (5) / hidden (6)

```
CustomTabsServiceConnection customTabsServiceConnection = new CustomTabsServiceConnection() {
            @Override
            public void onCustomTabsServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, CustomTabsClient customTabsClient) {
                client = customTabsClient;
                client.warmup(0L);
                customTabsSession = client.newSession(new CustomTabsCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onNavigationEvent(int navigationEvent, @Nullable Bundle extras) {
                        super.onNavigationEvent(navigationEvent, extras);
                    }
            }
}
```

You can then bind this and the callbacks will start triggering when you use it when launching your tabs (SDK <= 29, it will be different on 30)

```
    String packageName = CustomTabsClient.getPackageName(this, null);
    boolean didSucceed = CustomTabsClient.bindCustomTabsService(this, packageName, mCustomTabsServiceConnection);

    CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder(customTabsSession);
```